# how to map AspNetuserClaims to AspNetUserRoles

Tags: asp.net-identity

in Asp.Net Identity, Aspnetuserclaims has user id but no roled id
i have custom claims, i want to add claims to roleids.

I can do by adding new claims table, but my solution is rejected by client
I need to use identity to map claims to roles

How  to map,need an idea

Thanks

Comment: If you need to add claims to roles then you'll need to extend identity to store the information. How else can you persist the roleclaims? Adding a roleclaims table doesn't break identity as asp.net identity is fully extensible. So nothing wrong with the proposed solution. E.g. with ApplicationUser you extend IdentityUser so you can add additional properties.

Comment: problem is they want me to use the existing identity,without extending it with any new tables

Comment: If there's no room to store the information then you can't. One alternative would be not to use roleclaims. But what is their idea of how it should be done instead? Adding a table outside the identity model? I think the answer to this question is to work this out together with your client.

Comment: How to add a table inside identity?I have seen adding additional properties in user.identity which i did.I want to add roles column to Aspnetuserclaims table  but it seems to be no way to add using code first approach.Am trying to use userid on claims table and userid on roles to get it done but its a big loop am doing.